# CListCtrl force LVN_ITEMCHANGED notification clicking on the same item

Tags: mfc, click, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl that which parent handles item changing with

ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST_CTRL, OnItemchangedListCtrl)

Everything works great, except when I click on the same already selected item. I know the selection has not changed, but I wanna force the behaviuor handled by this routine.

I already tried to handle this, like that

ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGING, IDC_LIST_CTRL, OnItemchangingListCtrl)

```
void CMyWindow::OnItemchangingListCtrl(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    *pResult=0;
}
```

as I've read somewhere if iI set * pRresult to 0 it will force the ITEMCHANGED processing. Nice try, but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call OnItemChangedListCtrl() yourself from OnItemchangingListCtrl()?